# How to disable a form after the first submission?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" onsubmit="document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled=true;">
```

I use that line to disable the button after the first click, but it doesnt work..

Here is the line of the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit-button"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are posting to the same page and wish for the button to be disabled after the form has been submitted once, what you can do is use PHP to check if the data that was submitted by the form has been posted to the page. If it has, disable the button. It might look like this:

`<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" <? if (isset($_POST['your_form_data'])) echo "disabled='disabled'" ?> >`

Comment: This has worked..once the registration completes itself:                 echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled=true;</script>';

Comment: @WithFlyingColors this is wrong solution from wrong assumption. there should be HTTP redirect after submit, not the same form output.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that what is happening is your code is firing but then page will refresh after the form has been submitted and the button will no longer be disabled.

If this is the case then the you could insert the disabled property in to the button's HTML from the server side when you know that the page is being rendered as the result of the form being submitted.

Comment: hmmm.. I see, so do I need to mix php and javascript code.. do something link this  if($_Post['registrationSuccess']){  <script> document.getelementbyID("button")=disable</script>}..will that work..But I guess it wouldnt on a page refresh

Comment: Yes - something like that should work. Or, I think you could put some in-line php in the buttons HTML mark-up to inject the 'disabled' property.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to save a boolean flag in database for example `isRegistered`, so if the user is already registered, the form will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery (just an example, better to use jquery):

```
function disablebtn( idbtn ) {
    document.getElementById(idbtn).innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    document.getElementById(idbtn).disabled=true;
}

<form onsubmit="disablebtn('formPageBtn')">

    <button type="submit" id="formPageBtn">Send</button>
</form>
```

With this function when you press the button it will change the label to "loading...", too.

Comment: this question has nothing to what you answer is

Comment: @david: do you read the text of the question? **disable the button after the first click**

Comment: yeah i did, i dont mean to be rude, a few minutes a go someone else posted a jquery version answer like yours and someone voted him down, and looks like hes removed his answer

Answer (score 0):

change the action to `javascript:void%200` after the form was send!

Answer (score -1):

In what way does it "not work"?

If you mean that it doesn't submit the form, the button just stays disabled, try using a setTimeout to delay the disabling slightly.

If you mean that the button is not disabling, are you sure the page isn't reloading by the form being submitted? If this is what's happening, you might want to add `<?php if($_POST) echo " disabled"; ?>` inside your submit button.